# How to add Search message "Not found" in my php code?

Tags: php, mysql, search, pdo

I want to get "Car not found!" message in this code. Please help me...
How to get this message?

```
<?php 
//Query for Listing count
$brand=$_POST['brand'];
$fueltype=$_POST['fueltype'];
$sql = "SELECT id from tblvehicles where tblvehicles.VehiclesBrand=:brand and tblvehicles.FuelType=:fueltype";
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query -> bindParam(':brand',$brand, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query -> bindParam(':fueltype',$fueltype, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$cnt=$query->rowCount();
?>
<p><span><?php echo htmlentities($cnt);?> Listings</span></p>
</div>
</div>
```

*Where to write echo to get this message?*

```
$sql = "SELECT tblvehicles.*,tblbrands.BrandName,tblbrands.id as bid  from tblvehicles join tblbrands on tblbrands.id=tblvehicles.VehiclesBrand where tblvehicles.VehiclesBrand=:brand and tblvehicles.FuelType=:fueltype";
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query -> bindParam(':brand',$brand, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query -> bindParam(':fueltype',$fueltype, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($results as $result)
{  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside of an `else` conditional chained to your `$query->rowCount()`:

```
if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
    foreach($results as $result) { 
        // Output the successful results
    }
} else {
    echo "Car not found!";
}
```

Comment: Why I get syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)?

if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($results as $result)
{  // Output the successful results
    } else {
    echo "Car not found!";
} ?>

Comment: Because you actually need to **output** something where I have the commented code. It depends on what you want to display, but even replacing the comment with a basic `var_dump($result)` will work :)

Comment: I tried this:
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($results as $result)
{ 
var_dump($result)
    }
} else {
    echo "Car not found!";
}  ?>
But not works,unexpected "}" and when I remove them unexpected "else"... Where I am wrong? :(

Answer (score 0):

You already have your if statement to check if your rowcount > 0 (i.e. it has something to return), and print out the result. You can just add an else to that where you echo out your message.